# how do I export a part as a .stp in CATIA 3DExperience Macro

Tags: vba, catia

How can I use a VBA macro in the 3DExperience to save a part as a step file? I have found references in the documentation to the ExportData method, which requires it to be referred to a document, but I cannot figure out how to get the current active document. In an example I found online for CATIA V5 they use the "Open" method to convert files, but I would like to refer to the current active document instead, how could I do this?

Thanks!!!

```
Dim PartDocument0 As Document
' Reading a CATPart file
Set PartDocument0 = CATIA.Documents.Open("C:\desktop\File1.CATPart")
' Saving the part in a STEP file
PartDocument0.ExportData("C:\desktop\File1.stp", "stp")
```

Documentation references:

**Exportdata**

> Sub ExportData(fileName As String, format As String)
>
> Member of INFITF.Document

**ActiveDocument**

> Property ActiveDocument As Document
>
> Member of INFITF.CATIAApplicationCoClass read-only

**Document**

> Sub ExportData(fileName As String, format As String)
>
> Member of INFITF.Document

**Application**

> Property Application As CATIAApplicationCoClass
>
> read-only
>
> Member of INFITF.AnyObject

But if I run the following code:

```
Dim PartDocument1 As Application
Set PartDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument
```

or even the following code:

```
Dim PartDocument1 As Documents
Set PartDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument
```

I get the error:

> Method "ActiveDocument" of object "Application" failed

Comment: Please have a look on the `ActiveDocument` of the application object (e.g. _Set oPartDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument_)

Comment: Unfortunately the CATIA object has no ActiveDocument properties or method

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? (I guess instead of _ActiveDocument_ there is a _ActiveEditor_ Object)

Comment: I've added some references to the documentation, ExportData is a method of Document object, so I can't une it on the Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an equivalent of the ExportData function with 3DExperience. Only thing I have found close to a solution is using StartCommand and SendKeys functions to simulate key presses:
https://www.coe.org/p/fo/et/thread=28059

yet it is not a robust solution, tho it may solve your problem. I would really appreciate it if you came up with a solution and share it.

Comment: I reached the same conclusion, there isn't a way to make it programmatically.